# Stuck on Authorizing Application

Tags: bug, ios-app

Downloaded the beta app, opened it, choose to log with open id (custom) got redirected to a [simpleid](http://www.simpleid.org) website, put in credentials, got redirected back to stack exchange to the page with the stack exchange header and a blank page under that, saying "Authorizing application" waited for 5 minutes nothing else happened.
[image]

Comment: Was able to reproduce even using openid.stackexchange.com as the custom URL

Comment: +1 Same problem. I am logging in using a Yahoo OpenID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some server-side issues which had broken the openID login flow. This was combined with a front-end issue in the iOS app which prevented the flow from completing successfully.

You should be able to login correctly in the next app update, which will be **version  1.1.0.127**.

Comment: Would you like me to accept the answer or to retest when 1.1.0.127 is out or does not matter?

Comment: @zespri best if you can restest when 1.1.0.127 is out and then accept the answer.

Comment: Works properly in 1.1.0.132